# xlSheetType as listed on the doc.microsoft.com webpage is incorrect

Tags: excel, vba, documentation

I noticed an error on the MS documentation website: xlChart as a VBA constant in Excel is not defined with the correct value (the "sheet.type" for a chart sheet is 3, not xlChart).

Can the correction of the value of xlChart be considered in a future update of Excel please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the place for issues about the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's "correct" but only in the sense of when it's used with the  `Sheets.Add` method.

```vb
? xlsheettype.xlChart
-4109 
? xlsheettype.xlDialogSheet
-4116 
? xlsheettype.xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet
 4 
? xlsheettype.xlExcel4MacroSheet
 3 
? xlsheettype.xlWorksheet
-4167
```

This matches the listing at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlsheettype?view=excel-pia

The issue for *existing* sheets has been noticed:  https://excel.tips.net/T002538_Detecting_Types_of_Sheets_in_VBA.html

However this:

```vb
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=XlSheetType.xlChart
End With
```

does add a chart sheet to the workbook.

Comment: The problem I'm having is when looking for the .type property of a sheet object I was hoping to identify a chart by checking against xlChart ... that's not possible since xlChart is different from "3", which is the type of a chart sheet in the Sheets collection

Comment: The code in the second link shows how to work around that.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm a regular follower of the ExcelTips blog, but somehow missed that post ... it's a great workaround which I'll incorporate as an idea. A shame though that such workaround is necessary, because of an inconsistency in the Excel object model introduced (but not documented) by MS ...

Comment: I agree - would be nice to have it all work the same way (adding a sheet and checking an existing sheet)